# BASH script to extract UUID/PARTUUID from Variable

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I'm trying to develop a bash setup script that includes mounting and migrating a boot drive.  I've got most of it working, but would like to populate my `/boot/cmdline.txt` and `fstab` files with drive `UUID` and `PARTUUID` numbers.

I basically set a variable with the output of `blkid`:

```
disk=$(blkid)
echo "${disk}"

RESULT:
/dev/mmcblk0p1: LABEL_FATBOOT="boot" LABEL="boot" UUID="69D5-9B27" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="d9b3f436-01"
/dev/mmcblk0p2: LABEL="rootfs" UUID="24eaa08b-10f2-49e0-8283-359f7eb1a0b6" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="d9b3f436-02"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="usbfs" UUID="493b6467-7b7b-4291-a86d-dea5e842780b" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="83122dbb-cacf-4612-9be2-4301a03e8093"
/dev/mmcblk0: PTUUID="d9b3f436" PTTYPE="dos"
```

My goal is to set one variable to capture the `/dev/sda1` value for UUID and the other for the same drives PARTUUID.  My basic premise is to do something like this (based on being able to do this in python:

```
#sudo code#
Disk=diskInfo

While line in Disk; do
    If Line contains /dev/sda1
        Then
            Do some Regex to set vUUID = "493b6467-7b7b-4291-a86d-dea5e842780b"
            Do some Regex to set vPARTUUID = "83122dbb-cacf-4612-9be2-4301a03e8093"
```

I think I want something like this - - but can't get it to work:

```
disk=$(blkid)

while read line; do
    if [[ $line == '/dev/sda1'* ]]; then
        if [[ $line =~  UUID=(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1 ]]; then  #captures too much
            vUUID=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        fi
        if [[ $line =~  PARTUUID=(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1 ]]; then  #captures too much
            vPARTUUID=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        fi
    fi
done <<< "$disk"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a loop here.

```
$ IFS=\" read -r _ vUUID _ vPARTUUID _ < <(blkid /dev/sda1 -s UUID -s PARTUUID)
$
$ echo $vUUID 
9099-AD46
$
$ echo $vPARTUUID 
90afc43c-5b4d-4721-b82a-000e585fef62
```

If there is no such disk `read` will silently fail with a non-zero exit status; so you can use it as a condition in an if-else expression.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there.
Would you please try:

```
pat='^/dev/sda1.* UUID="([^"]+)".* PARTUUID="([^"]+)"'
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ $pat ]]; then
        vUUID="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        vPARTUUID="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    fi
done < <(blkid)
```

result:

```
echo "vUUID=$vUUID"
vUUID=493b6467-7b7b-4291-a86d-dea5e842780b

echo "vPARTUUOID=$vPARTUUID"
vPARTUUOID=83122dbb-cacf-4612-9be2-4301a03e8093
```

Hope this helps.